# Find and Replace ALL function in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, find, replace

We are trying to figure out if there is a way to find and replace a "\n" string with the character "-" (hyphen).

Excel does a great job finding and replacing all, but not sure how to do same function in QGIS.

[image]

Note that the attribute table contains about 1000 of these strings so it would have to be a function that would look within the string for the \n characters without having to input the specific string by hand, if that makes sense.

Comment: are you using shapefiles?

Comment: Yes these are .shps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with this expression in the field calculator:

```
regexp_replace( "yourfield", '\\\\n', '-')
```

This sould replace all the `\n` substrings with `-`.

Comment: Why are there four slashes before the 'n' ?

Comment: @csk I can't give you a detailed explanation, but long story short: in regular expressions, `\n` must be escaped as `\\n`; in addition, all \ must be escaped as \\ in QGIS regex engines. So 4 backslashes at the end of the story ;)